# Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration spring boot (security) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am learning spring security and was trying to run this project but its giving me an error.

I am not able to understand what to do.  Here is the Github [link](https://github.com/jgrandja/messaging-sample), Youtube video [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N-xwmoN83w) that I'm following.

When I try to run the client app it is running fine but when I try to run resource server its not running, its giving me the errors:

> 1. Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8090/uaa/oauth/token"
> 2. I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8090/uaa/oauth/token/.well-known/openid-configuration":
>      Connection refused: connect; nested exception is
>      java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

The stack trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8090/uaa/oauth/token"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8090/uaa/oauth/token"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.getOpenidConfiguration(JwtDecoders.java:78) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:48) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8090/uaa/oauth/token/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RC3.jar:5.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.getOpenidConfiguration(JwtDecoders.java:76) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Please help me to solve this error I am new to spring security.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that an app should be running on port 8090 and that it does not (this is where the I/O error comes from).

Could you check if you have anything running on this port on your computer ?
If something was running on this port the app would respond with a 404 or something like this. Maybe the app crashed at launch and you didn't see it ?

Comment: no I checked nothing else was running on those ports so and thanks for your advice please can you tell me are you experienced in java(Spring and hibernate) i need some help and advice from you and you can also mail me at-->  ag.rajat113@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Rajat, i am also facing same issue, did you find any solution